# Runtime Android exception after pressing a button to go to next Activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I have this code:

```
package com.problemio;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class ProblemioActivity extends Activity 
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button addProblemButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.add_problem_button);   
        Button browseProblemsButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.browse_problems_button);   
        Button searchProblemsButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.search_problems_button);   
        Button myProblemsButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.my_problems_button);           

        addProblemButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() 
        {  
            public void onClick(View v) {
              Intent myIntent = new Intent(ProblemioActivity.this, AddProblemActivity.class);
              ProblemioActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        });        
    }
}
```

It compiles fine and displays the addProblemButton button, but when that button is clicked, the system gives a runtime exception.

Here is the AddProblemActivity class:

```
package com.problemio;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AddProblemActivity extends Activity 
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        //TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.addProblemText);
        //text.setText(R.string.addProblemText);        

        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText("Please Add a Problem");
        setContentView(tv);        
    }
}
```

and here is the layout main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="First, add the problem you want to solve!"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/add_problem_text"    
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Add a Problem You Want To See Solved"
    />    

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/add_problem_button"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Add a Problem"
    />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/browse_problems_button"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Browse Problems"

    />
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/search_problems_button"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Search Problems"
    />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/my_problems_button"        
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="View My Problems"
    />    
</LinearLayout>
```

any idea what might be going wrong? By the way, I can't seem to locate the stack trace of the exception. Where should I look for that in Eclipse? All it currently shows me is AndroidRuntimeException - dalvik.system.NativeStart.main

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only problem I can think of is that your Activity "`AddProblemActivity`" is not register in the manifest.

See the logs under LogCat...you will find it in Window >Show View >Android > LogCat

Comment: thanks - yes probably that might be it. How do I register it in the manifest? :)

Comment: btw I had LogCat open, but it only gave the one-line of the exception and not the full stack trace.

Comment: Sorry for late reply....i saw it just now....but its good that you figured it out on your own...:)